# add_rewrite_rule() driving me crazy, rewrite not working when analyzer says it should

Tags: rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I have a special situation and need some help achieving the final step.

**Background:**

When I access *mydomain.com/category/postname*, I get the post as expected.

When I access *mydomain.com/category/postname?ajax=1*, I get the post html (baked into and including its corresponding page template markup, which is extremely important for this use case), but I get it rendered **without** its header and footer (I did this on purpose, with a $_GET['ajax']==1 conditional inside the header.php and footer.php files to suppress them).

**This all works as expected.** However, it leaves me with a new small problem... Browsers won't properly cache content from URLs that end with a GET parameter string.

**Therefore,** I would like to create a rewrite rule that achieves the following...

*mydomain.com/ajax/category/postname*
**becomes**
*mydomain.com/category/postname?ajax=1*

**Here's from my functions.php:**

```
function dynaload_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('ajax/(.*)/?', '$matches[1]?ajax=1', 'bottom');
}
add_action('init', 'dynaload_rewrite');
```

**This results in .htaccess file as follows:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*)/? /$matches[1]?ajax=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Expected Result:** When I access */ajax/category/postname* I want the content from */category/postname* to render, minus the header and footer, as they do if I access normally with *?ajax=1*

**Actual Result:** I am receiving the content from my WordPress 404 page, however the header and footer **are** omitted (so I know that the parameter ajax=1 is being passed correctly, it's just loading the wrong page).

Successful help is appreciated and will be deemed to be impressive. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/?

Answer (score 0):

Your external rule doesn't work because you're using a format that only works for internal rules- `$matches[1]` is essentially nonsense in the context of an .htaccess file. Using the `$matches` array will only work when rules are parsed by PHP, external rules need to use the standard `$1` instead of `$matches[1]`. Any rule that doesn't point to `index.php` is interpreted as an external rule and gets added to .htaccess instead of the internal rules array.

That said, I suggest changing things a bit and [adding a rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) instead of a rule. Your URLs would be:

> http://example.com/category/postname/ajax/

You could then check if `get_query_var('ajax')` is set in your templates.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It doesn't work with $1 either, though... However I will try your alternate solution and report back

Comment: Your solution only partially works. When I add the following: `add_rewrite_endpoint( 'ajax', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES | EP_ALL );` I am getting 301's for all posts, and some pages. Instead of what I want which is the content (although I get the content for category archives and certain pages for some reason).

Comment: have you flushed rewrite rules?

Comment: Yes. I should also mention that I am using "Custom Structure" which is `/learning-library/%postname%/`, and that I had to type `category` into the "Category Base" in order to get category archive pages to work at all (even though `category` is supposed to be the default). Setting that, then re-flushing, makes it so that when I request `/ajax/1/` I am getting correct behaviour on category archive pages, correct behaviour on basic pages (including those in subfolders), but I am getting 301's on learning-library/postname every time. **In other words everything works now except blog posts.**

Comment: I'm still getting 301's for anything under `/learning-library/slugname/ajax/1` that's pointing to the vanilla `/learning-library/slugname`. Does anyone know where those 301's are coming from and why my custom endpoint isn't picking up on blog posts?

Answer (score 0):

This works to capture the category and post_name then changes the template rendered.

```
if (!class_exists('WPTestPluginEndpoint')):

    class WPTestPluginEndpoint
    {
        const ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME = 'ajax';

        // WordPress hooks

        public function init()
        {
            add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'add_query_vars'), 0);
            add_action('parse_request', array($this, 'sniff_requests'), 0);
            add_action('init', array($this, 'add_endpoint'), 0);
        }

        // Add public query vars

        public function add_query_vars($vars)
        {
            $vars[] = 'ajax';
            $vars[] = 'cat';
            $vars[] = 'post_name';

            return $vars;
        }

        // Add API Endpoint

        public function add_endpoint()
        {
            add_rewrite_rule('^ajax/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?ajax=1&cat=$matches[1]&post_name=$matches[2]', 'top');

            flush_rewrite_rules(false); //// <---------- REMOVE THIS WHEN DONE
        }

        // Sniff Requests

        public function sniff_requests($wp_query)
        {
            global $wp;

            if (isset($wp->query_vars['ajax'])) {

                $_REQUEST ['ajax'] = $wp->query_vars['ajax'];
                $_REQUEST ['cat'] = $wp->query_vars['cat'];
                $_REQUEST ['post_name'] = $wp->query_vars['post_name'];

                $this->handle_request(); // handle it
            }
        }

        // Handle Requests

        protected function handle_request()
        {
            // Control the template used

            add_filter('template_include', function ($original_template) {

                $args = array(
                    'cat' => $_REQUEST['cat'],
                    'post_name' => $_REQUEST['post_name'],
                );

                //var_dump($original_template);

                return get_template_directory() . '/single.php';
            });
        }
    }

    $wptept = new WPTestPluginEndpoint();
    $wptept->init();

endif; // WPTestPluginEndpoint
```

In your template

```
if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['ajax'] ) ) get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['ajax'] ) ) get_footer(); ?>
```